# Размытое отражение трансляции на фон

Tags: java, blur, rtmp

Я делаю приложение, похожее на Rave. Суть его в совместном просмотре видео. Как и в оригинальном приложении, я бы хотел создать отражение трансляции на фон, как показано на картинке.

Я реализовал это так:

1. Беру `Bitmap` с моего `textureView`, где показывается трансляция (60 кадров в секунду):

```
Bitmap frameBitmap = textureView.getBitmap();
```

2. Делаю размытие `Bitmap` с помощью RenderScript Intrinsics Replacement Toolkit:

```
Bitmap blurredBitmap = Toolkit.INSTANCE.blur(frameBitmap, 25);
```

3. Подгоняю размытый размер `Bitmap` под нужную мне ширину и высоту:

```
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width-top_W, height-top_H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(frameBitmap, (int)(-croppedBitmap.getWidth()*1.5), -top_H, null);
```

4. Устанавливаю на фон:

```
BG_View.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), croppedBitmap));
```

Всё круто, за исключением того, что фон отстаёт от трансляции на какие-то доли секунды. Я очень хочу реализовать моментальное отражение, но совсем не понимаю, как иначе это можно сделать. (Без размытия отражение так же отстаёт от трансляции).

[image: Нынешний вид приложения]

Comment: "Без размытия отражение так же отстаёт от трансляции" - значит размытие тут не при чем. А значит и для вопроса оно лишняя подробность.

Comment: Возможно есть решение, которое может сделать моментальное отражение трансляции, но не сможет размыть его в будущем, я точно не знаю. Я просто попытался описать мою проблему более подробно